# Android hardware and Adobe AIR

Tags: android, flash, air, hardware, flash-cs5

Do any of you know a method that an Android application built using Adobe Flash can access hardware API on the device?

For example, I launch Flash CS5 and create a new AIR for Android application. The application consists only of a button. When that button is pressed the wireless on the device toggles. This is easy to do in Java by just creating a wifiManager:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true/false);
```

But how would you do it in an AIR application? Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't access native API from AIR.

But if you really want it there's [a hack](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aloPzOIFxhnMJ%3aelromdesign.com/blog/2010/10/29/hacking-native-android-with-air-app-to-allow-air-access-unavailable-apis/&hl=en&client=firefox-a&strip=1) to do this ...