# Android hardware and Adobe AIR cont

Tags: android, flash, actionscript, air, flash-cs5

I asked in a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889376/android-hardware-and-adobe-air) if it was possible to access native API from AIR. [LadaRaider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/533552/ladaraider) answered that it was not, but linked me to a site with a hack around it. Today I noticed a default AIR application in Flash that uses the accelerometer on an Android device to move a ball around. Can anyone explain this?

```
import flash.events.Event;

var accelX:Number;
var accelY:Number;

var fl_Accelerometer:Accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
fl_Accelerometer.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, fl_AccelerometerUpdateHandler);
function fl_AccelerometerUpdateHandler(event:AccelerometerEvent):void
{
    accelX = event.accelerationX;
    accelY = event.accelerationY;
}

ball.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);
function moveBall(evt:Event)
{
    ball.x -= accelX*30;
    ball.y += accelY*30;

    if(ball.x > (480-ball.width/2))
    {
        ball.x = 480-ball.width/2;
    }
    if(ball.x < (0+ball.width/2))
    {
        ball.x = 0+ball.width/2;
    }
    if(ball.y > (800-ball.width/2))
    {
        ball.y = 800-ball.width/2;
    }
    if(ball.y < (0+ball.width/2))
    {
        ball.y = 0+ball.width/2;
    }
}
```

Where is this `AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE` coming from?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`flash.sensors` package](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/sensors/package-detail.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3accelerometer/) is an example tutorial for accelerometer in AS3.